# SQL Stored Procedure error by updating

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

Im trying to use a stored procedure with parameter, in this case the OrderID.
But i'm getting the error : **'Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).'**

My C# methode:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateStock", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrderId;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateStock] @OrderID int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Products SET Stock = Stock -1 FROM Products INNER JOIN 
OrderDetails ON 
Products.ProductId = OrderDetails.ProductID WHERE OrderDetails.OrderID = 
@OrderID
END
GO
```

Maybe you guys can help me out?

Comment: You have a trigger on Products table that's triggering itself or other triggers that are chaining together.

Comment: you are not calling your procedure recursively, so there must be a trigger on the `Products` table. could you show the code of this trigger too?

Comment: @EzLo It was a trigger, Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code you provided so far looks fine. However the error is saying something like - somewhere, a stored procedure is calling another stored procedure and then again and again.. too many times. It could also mean that there is 1 stored procedure calling itself too many times.

So the provided code doesn't show this behavior so I would suggest looking elsewhere. As mentioned in the comments a good place to look are the triggers on the Products table. A trigger might run when you try to update it which could be the root of the problem.